# Complex sql count query to get violations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Weapons` which contains `weaponIds` and `weaponType` as columns.

```
| weaponIds   | weaponType  |

 1                       gun
 2                       gun
 3                       gun
 4                       tank
 5                       tank
 6                       bomb
 7                       bomb
 8                       bomb
```

I have another table called `WeaponUsage` with columns as `weaponIds` and `userIds`.

```
 | weaponIds   |    userIds  |

     1                  user1
     1                  user2
     2                  user1
     5                  user2
     6                  user2
```

A user can use multiple weapons of different types. However a user should hold only one weapon from a given type. That is, a user cannot have multiple weapons of same type.

Because my system was compromised, I do have instances in second table where a User has multiple weapons of same type.

I want to make a report which finds all such violations. Given a `weaponType`, my result table should contain all `userIds` against `weaponIds` of given  type and the count of that weapon. e.g. user1 above should be reported as he has 2 weapons of type gun, but user2 is fine as he has multiple weapons but of different types.

How to achieve this in a single sql query? I have sql server as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
select userid,count(distinct weapontype) from weapons a inner join WeaponUsage b
on a.weaponIds=b.weaponIds 
group by userid
having count(distinct weapontype)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    userIds,
    count(distinct weaponType)
FROM
    Weapons w
INNER JOIN
    WeaponUsage wu
ON
    w.weaponIds = wu.weaponIds
GROUP BY 
    userIds
HAVING 
    count(distinct weaponType) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like grouping to me:

```
WITH Weapons AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
 (1, 'gun'),
 (2, 'gun'),
 (3, 'gun'),
 (4, 'tank'),
 (5, 'tank'),
 (6, 'bomb'),
 (7, 'bomb'),
 (8, 'bomb')) T(weaponId, weaponType)
), WeaponUsage AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
 (1, 'user1'),
 (1, 'user2'),
 (2, 'user1'),
 (5, 'user2'),
 (6, 'user2')) T(weaponId, userId)
)
SELECT userId, weaponType, COUNT(*) [#WeaponsOfType]
FROM Weapons W
JOIN WeaponUsage U ON W.weaponId=U.weaponId
GROUP BY userId, weaponType
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Result:

```
userId   weaponType   #WeaponsOfType
------   ----------   --------------
user1    gun          2
```